# MDX IMPOSSIBLE TO ORDER

Tags: mdx, dimension

i can't order by the countryname in the following query:

```
   SELECT
   {
          [MEASURES].[TICKETS]
   } ON COLUMNS,
   ORDER
   (
          [LOCALIZATION].[BYGEO].[COUNTRY].MEMBERS *
          [LOCALIZATION].[IDCOUNTRY].[IDCOUNTRY].MEMBERS,
          [LOCALIZATION].[BYGEO].[COUNTRY].MEMBERS, ASC
   ) ON ROWS

   FROM [CUBE]
```

I'm trying to order by COUNTRY (country name) not by IDCOUNTRY, but i can't achive it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ORDER
   (
          [LOCALIZATION].[BYGEO].[COUNTRY].MEMBERS *
          [LOCALIZATION].[IDCOUNTRY].[IDCOUNTRY].MEMBERS,
          [LOCALIZATION].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME, ASC
   ) ON ROWS
```